# Почему переменная изменяет свое значение?

Tags: java, for

Есть такой кусок кода. Не могу понять почему x=i+1,а не x=i.

```
         public class Main{
             public static void main(String[] args){
                 int i;
                 for(i=0;i<=5;i++){
                     System.out.println("i:"+i);
                 }
                 int x=i;
                 System.out.println("x:"+x);
             }
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поймите, как работает цикл; для этого полезно его развернуть, рассмотреть пошагово:

1. Сначала выполняется `i = 0`
2. Затем проверяется условие `i <= 5`. Оно истинно, поэтому выполняется тело цикла, выводится `i:0`
3. Выполняется `i++`, теперь `i = 1`
4. Проверяется условие `i <= 5`. Оно истинно, поэтому выполняется тело цикла, выводится `i:1`
5. Затем выполняется `i++`, теперь `i = 2`
6. Проверяется условие `i <= 5`. Оно истинно, выполняется тело цикла, выводится `i:2`
7. Затем выполняется `i++`, теперь `i = 3`
8. Проверяется условие `i <= 5`. Оно истинно, выполняется тело цикла, выводится `i:3`
9. Затем выполняется `i++`, теперь `i = 4`
10. Проверяется условие `i <= 5`. Оно истинно, выполняется тело цикла, выводится `i:4`
11. Затем выполняется `i++`, теперь `i = 5`
12. Проверяется условие `i <= 5`. Оно истинно, выполняется тело цикла, выводится `i:5`
13. Затем выполняется `i++`, теперь `i = 6`
14. Проверяется условие `i <= 5`. Оно ложно, поэтому цикл обрывается, идём дальше.
15. Выполняется `x = i`, то есть 6, это значение и выводится.

Получается, что цикл `for` завершается тогда, когда итератор заходит дальше последнего обрабатываемого элемента, в данном случае это `5 + 1` (а, например, в цикле по указателям в Си "запредельным" элементом будет `null`).

Answer (score 0):

Потому что вот тут

```
for(i=0;i<=5;i++){
```

сказано, что **после** каждой итерации увеличь значение переменной на 1. Соответственно **в конце** последней итерации, уже **после** того как выведет `System.out.println("i:"+i);` значение увеличится с 5 до 6

Comment: Спасибо:)......